# JsRender incompatible with PhoneGap on Android?

Tags: cordova, jsrender

I would like to use JsRender in a PhoneGap Jquery Mobile project.
When I run my application in a simple browser (for example Firefox), everything works fine.
When I run the application in Android emulator I get the following error in console:

D/CordovaLog(603): file:///android_asset/www/js/program.js: Line 45 : TypeError: Result of expression '$("#vehicletemplate").render' [undefined] is not a function.

Please advice. Is there anybody who try JsRender in Phonegap with Jquery Mobile on Android 2.1?

Comment: Is JsRender library getting loaded correctly, after jQuery? Is $.render defined for example. If so, you could try creating your template from a string, instead, and calling render as in this example: http://borismoore.github.com/jsviews/demos/jQueryConfDemosOct2011/03_compiled-template.html

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you get a resolution on this problem?